# ORA-00936: missing expression issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to oracle sql and I'm trying to run the following query but getting above mentioned error.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CASE WHEN DATEPART (Hour,  OrderTime) < 5 
                    THEN DATEADD(Day, -1, CONVERT(date, ordertime))
                    ELSE CONVERT(date, ordertime)
                    END) AS ItemOrderTradingDate FROM TBL_ITEM
```

Please help.

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) did you find `dateadd()` or `datepart()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to extract "hour" from a date column. If that's so, see these two options:

```
SQL> select ordertime,
  2         to_char(ordertime, 'hh24') hour_1,
  3         extract(hour from cast(ordertime as timestamp)) hour_2
  4  from tbl_item;

ORDERTIME           HOUR_1       HOUR_2
------------------- -------- ----------
06.04.2020 08:01:05 08                8

SQL>
```

Error you got when running Ankint's query was because `extract` - for certain values (hours, minutes, seconds) works on *timestamps*, not *dates*.

---

I'm not familiar with functions you used (`convert`, `datepart`, `dateadd`) so I can't tell what you really want to do once you find which hour it is. `dateadd` looks like you'd want to add (or subtract) 1 day from some data value. If that's so, then just do it: date arithmetic is (by default) done by days anyway:

```
SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate + 1 tomorrow,
  3         sysdate - 1 yesterday
  4  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           TOMORROW            YESTERDAY
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
06.04.2020 08:05:34 07.04.2020 08:05:34 05.04.2020 08:05:34

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM OrderTime) < 5 
                 THEN TRUNC(ordertime) - 1
            ELSE TRUNC(ordertime)
       END AS ItemOrderTradingDate
FROM TBL_ITEM
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit. I'm getting following error;

ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source